# How do I add <!--more--> tag to all wordpress posts?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to add `<!--more-->` tag to all my WordPress posts after 30 words or 200  characters in each post.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I think you looking for [the_excerpt()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) function. Another one: [Read More](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

Answer (score 0):

Adding  tags to your posts manually is not a long term solution as you have to do it manually every time or make a custom plugin in for that. I think using the [the_excerpt()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) function is the best option you have.

If you cannot decide which one to use then please go through '[How to properly use more tags](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-properly-use-the-more-tag-in-wordpress/)' and you'll get a better understanding of which one to use in your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can write php script, my algorithm below:

```
get posts from DB as array
foreach content do
  replace \s* with \s
  if content length > 200
    explode content using ' '
    if array length >=30
     add tag after 30th item
     implode array with ' '
    else
     add tag after 200 chars using strpos
    update row
```